mantine ui connect to the next js project, it get 404 error line
`> next dev
▲ Next.js 14.2.4

Local:        http://localhost:3000

✓ Starting...
✓ Ready in 3.6s
○ Compiling / ...
✓ Compiled / in 5.8s (717 modules)
GET / 200 in 6145ms
○ Compiling /_not-found ...
✓ Compiled /_not-found in 4.8s (706 modules)
GET /_next/static/chunks/app/UnstyledButton.module.css.mjs.map 404 in 4971ms
GET / 200 in 115ms
GET /_next/static/chunks/app/UnstyledButton.module.css.mjs.map 404 in 36ms`
this is the error line.
this error show after change app/layout.tsx
how to fix this
i also try to edit template. but same error happen

I got the same error. have you got it fixed?

Same problem, any insight?

I suggest you to create an issue here https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues
